# Can I say 爸, or do I have to say 爸爸?

Tags: pronouns

I will find that 爸 (bà) is father if I look it up in a dictionary, but I've never heard anyone say that or 媽, only 爸爸 and 媽媽.

But can I still say just 爸?

Comment: Absolutely, in fact , only little child say 爸爸, otherwise you wannt to act like a spoiled child.

Comment: Might vary by environment.  I certainly don't call my father 爸爸, but I might refer to him (to others) as 我爸爸.  (Only to people with whom I'm familiar, though.  Otherwise, I employ the usual 父親.)

Comment: Same as when you called your father "Dad" vs "Daddy" and your mother  "Mom" vs "Mommy".  "Daddy" and "Mommy" are similar to 爸爸 and 媽媽.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, there are many different ways to mean "father" in Chinese:

父亲：a formal and polite word, not usual for daily use

令尊：a very polite word to replace "your father"

家父: equals to “my father” when you are talking with someone else (more polite)

泰山 or 岳丈: a very polite way to call your wife's father，while "岳父" is more common

公公: your husband's father

爸爸 = 爸 = 老爹: just like "dad"

Comment: Also 老爸 is a possibility.

Comment: I called my father 爹

Comment: 父亲 is usually used for filling in the form about kinship

Answer (score 4):

可以的，但是单独的“爸”字是一种比较口语话的，一般情况下，在比较正式的文章上并不能使用。

Answer (score 3):

Yes,

In my mind,I always say "爸爸" or "妈妈" when I was children.

But now ,I always say them "爸" or "妈“ .

Because，"爸爸" or "妈妈"，It sounds very childish。

Answer (score 3):

通常人们从少年时期开始就叫自己的爸爸"爸"，但小孩通常都是说爸爸。但是，写文章的时候不能用爸，必须用爸爸。说活时，哪一个都能用。

Answer (score 2):

To be politer, you say 爸爸, although you can say 阿爸 with less formality and politeness, but 爸 is the worst. I get told off when I call my dad 爸. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

In Chinese, may things are repeated for emphasis, etc. For example, 转转弯弯 is the same thing as 转弯. This is another one of those types of things.

Answer (score 1):

actually,we use 爸爸 or 爸 as Dad.爸爸 and 爸,they are no difference.or you can say that 爸 is the abbreviation of 爸爸,the same as 妈 to 妈妈.but 爷 does not mean 爷爷,奶 does not mean 奶奶.usually,we translate father as 父亲,it is a very formal form of address.

Answer (score 0):

爸 既能当 father 也能当 dad.

如果你叫你爸，你可以直接说 爸(dad).

如果你大声呼喊你的爸爸——比如距离很远，你应该用 爸~爸~！感觉这样持续时间长，中间能换口气……

如果你跟别人提起你爸爸，你可以用 我爸 或者 我爸爸。

> 我爸40了。（重点在陈述我爸的年龄）

> 我爸爸是个科学家。（好像在强调 我的爸爸 优秀）

Answer (score 0):

You should always say 爸、媽 unless you are younger than 8.

Answer (score -1):

可以用单独的"爸"或者"妈"，只是"爸爸"和"妈妈"用得比较多一些

Answer (score -1):

I think 爸爸 more like daddy in English. And 爸 likes dad...